# PHP / MySQL varchar field entered as a number

Tags: php, mysql, post, insert, varchar

I have within a form a textbox named PO_Number. The form submit by post to another page the textbox value.

In the second page I get $_POST['PO_Number'] and enter in MySQL.

MySQL field is varchar(15). As soon as the string of PO_Number starts with a letter or a number everything is OK.

The problem: sometimes the PO (Purchase Order) number start with 00 or 000 and it is stored with a comma before the 00
For example:
GH93737 - works
9087893 - works
0011132 - entered in database as ,0011132 (see the comma?)

The insert looks normal:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (PO_Number, ....) VALUES ('".$_POST['PO_Number']."',......)");
```

Many thanks for your suggestions and your help.

Comment: Is $_POST untouched/unchanged until your mysql_query? Or do you have some kind of sanitize function run on it before?

Comment: No function. It's just plain PHP 4...

Comment: Can you put your complete mysql_query() code?

Comment: @PrasadRajapaksha Sure, no problem but it's nothing is the mysql_query() I'm sure.

Comment: Could you please post the structure of the table? That would help too.

Comment: Try escaping all of your values with mysqli_escape_string to see if the issue goes away or become more evident. There may be a wayward comma in there.

Comment: What happens when you try posting this as your PO number: `'); DROP TABLE table_name`?

Comment: @dkamins Sorry, I didn't get your solution. Do you want me to make a mistake in the SQL?

Comment: @MarcusAdams I know, it looks strange to me too... that the reason I posted here. Thanks everybody for your time.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I put the real escape string and it's working! Hurray! Many thanks.

Comment: @dkamins: error happens, since even if it would result in valid SQL (it probably wouldn't), then `mysql_query()` can only run single query at a time. xkcd's hacker mum wouldn't do much harm.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if this has something to do with your browser/server character encoding and how it's interpreting those specific numbers because all of those leading zeros and ones might be getting interpreted as a binary number?

Here's some brief info on that point:

> A character encoding tells the computer how to interpret raw zeroes and ones into real characters. It usually does this by pairing numbers with characters.

http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html

Comment: It can be. The app is installed on Windows 2008 Server under XAMPP.

Comment: I have tried the same app on the Linux Server and the PO_Number is entered corrected in the varchar(15) field as 0003434.

Comment: I put the mysql real escape string and it's working! Hurray! Many thanks to everybody.